# Add link to image in bxslider

Tags: bxslider

I am using the following code to create bxslider I am unable to make the images hyperlinked to a particular link i.e. I want to link each slide to a web address
Is this possible? The project has reached a point where I cannot change this to another jquery plugin

```
<div class=" slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li>
        <a href='http://www.sitename.net/surgery/' title=''><img src="/images/slide1.png" alt=""  /></a></li>
        <li>
        <a href='http://www.sitename.net/about-us/' title=''><img src="/images/slide2.png" alt=""  /></a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Which style had you used ?
I don't need all the style, just the specific part.
It's not clear for future readers.
I can not reproduce what the problem was.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/1240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a CSS problem here. As I don't know what your code is I would need the CSS. I tried it locally and it worked, may try:

```
.bxslider li {
    float:left;
}
.bxslider li a{
    height:inherit;
    width:inherit;
    display:block
}
```

if you don't really know what you are doing wrap the whole thing i just wrote in:

```
<style>*Your code goes here minus the stars!*</style>
```